# Running multiple servers

Tags: server, apache2

I've got 3 servers (physical machines) running on my home network, 2 ubuntu and a raspberry pi.  I use 2 for development work and 1 to run live websites.  It is easy to access all three internally simple using the local ip 192.168.1.xxx but I want to access 1 of the development servers from the internet.  I've no idea how to go about this.

I'm running apache2 and several virtual servers and I'm guessing there is a way to point a virtual server elsewhere on the lan.  Is that possible and how?

Comment: How do you access your production server from outside ?

Comment: I'm just using it for web traffic so through site domain names

Comment: You have an internet IP at home ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use several methods.

If your internet router allows you to **redirect ports**.
You may redirect the ports you like Asaph answer.
For ensuring the stability, you must fix the computers IP address.
Check [this post](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) for more details (it may change in case you have a different router)

Another method is to use the **DMZ** from your router, and then forward ports from the computer on the DMZ, I assume it's your production server.
Check [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-dmz-and-port-forwarding/) for more info.

You can also **forward ports** from your already accessible server, to the production server. Check [this](http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/) for more info.

Last, you can forward a URL from your production server using an **Apache virtualhost**. Check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/510758/how-to-pass-a-request-from-one-apache-server-to-another) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your home network probably includes a cable modem/router which has a configuration console usually accessible via an internal IP address (e.g. (192.168.xxx.xxx). Sometimes this address is shown on a sticker physically stuck to the cable modem. Login to the router and look for a "port forwarding" configuration item.